# logic equivalence question?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I am trying to prove how these 2 formulas are equivalent using logical equivalence laws.

(p ↔ q) → r     =    (¬p∧q)∨(¬q∧p)∨r

For  (p ↔ q) → r, What I tried to do was

(p → q) ∧ (q → p) V r  (Bi conditional law)

(p v ¬q) ∧ (q V ¬p) v r  (conditional law)

(¬q v p) ∧ (¬p v q) v r (commutative law)

From there I got stuck as I wasn't sure for the next equivalence law.

What would be next?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a small mistake as after the Conditional Law (and DeMorgan) you should get:

$$(p \land ¬q) \lor (q \land ¬p) \lor r $$

That is, you get:

$$((p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow p)) \rightarrow r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Conditional Law)}$$

$$\neg ((\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg q \lor p)) \lor r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\neg (\neg p \lor q) \lor \neg (\neg q \lor p)) \lor r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan x 2)}$$

$$(p \land \neg q) \lor (q \land \neg p) \lor r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Commutation)}$$

$$(q \land \neg p) \lor(p \land \neg q) \lor  r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Commutation x 2)}$$

$$(\neg p \land q) \lor(\neg q \land p) \lor  r$$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was thinking about adding Demorgan before, again I wasn't sure. Thanks again!

Comment: @Blueberry23 You're welcome!  Please do use MathJax for future posts ... it's not hard to use.